# Issue when migrating Hibernate Search from 5.9.2 to 5.10.1 - ClassNotFoundException: ExtendedBeanManager$LifecycleListener

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-search

I'm trying to migrate our project from Hibernate Search 5.9.2 to 5.10.1 but I encounter the following error when starting my Tomcat 8.

We are using:

- Java 8
- Tomcat 8
- Springframework 5.0.6
- Springframework security 5.0.5
- Springframework data jpa 2.0.7
- Hibernate 5.2.17
- Hibernate validator 6.0.10
- Hibernate search **5.10.1** *(5.9.2 works fine)*

The compilation through maven is fine and without any error.

The error is at Tomcat Startup.

Many thanks for any idea to solve this problem,

Marc

```
2018-05-31 17:05:12,518 INFO  [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource] HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-05-31 17:05:12,884 INFO  [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource] HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-05-31 17:05:12,994 INFO  [org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner] At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2018-05-31 17:05:13,092 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/]] 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
2018-05-31 17:05:13,244 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/]] Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2018-05-31 17:05:13,244 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
2018-05-31 17:05:13,284 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu May 31 17:05:13 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-05-31 17:05:13,427 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] Registering annotated classes: [class ec.ep.eo.eoweb.config.InternetConfiguration]
2018-05-31 17:05:17,088 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-05-31 17:05:18,165 INFO  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'JPA'
2018-05-31 17:05:18,225 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: JPA
    ...]
2018-05-31 17:05:18,619 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
2018-05-31 17:05:18,625 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-05-31 17:05:18,673 WARN  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ec.ep.eo.eoweb.config.BusinessConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/resource/beans/container/spi/ExtendedBeanManager$LifecycleListener
2018-05-31 17:05:18,673 INFO  [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource] HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-05-31 17:05:18,726 INFO  [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource] HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2018-05-31 17:05:18,734 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ec.ep.eo.eoweb.config.BusinessConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/resource/beans/container/spi/ExtendedBeanManager$LifecycleListener
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:579)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4810)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1692)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:465)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:415)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/resource/beans/container/spi/ExtendedBeanManager$LifecycleListener
    at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.ExtendedBeanManagerSynchronizerContributor.contribute(ExtendedBeanManagerSynchronizerContributor.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.applyServiceContributors(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:305)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.build(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:164)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:51)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1765)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.spi.ExtendedBeanManager$LifecycleListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1142)
    ... 69 more
2018-05-31 17:05:18,746 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ec.ep.eo.eoweb.config.BusinessConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/resource/beans/container/spi/ExtendedBeanManager$LifecycleListener
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:579)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4810)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1692)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
May 31, 2018 5:05:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
May 31, 2018 5:05:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:465)
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:415)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/resource/beans/container/spi/ExtendedBeanManager$LifecycleListener
    at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.ExtendedBeanManagerSynchronizerContributor.contribute(ExtendedBeanManagerSynchronizerContributor.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.applyServiceContributors(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:305)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.build(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:164)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:51)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1765)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.spi.ExtendedBeanManager$LifecycleListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1142)
    ... 69 more
2018-05-31 17:05:18,794 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/]] Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
[2018-05-31 05:05:18,833] Artifact eoweb-internet:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate Search 5.10 is only compatible with Hibernate ORM 5.3. See our compatibility matrix here: http://hibernate.org/search/releases/#compatibility-matrix .

So if you want to stay with ORM 5.2, you have to use Search 5.9 (the latest being 5.9.2.Final): http://hibernate.org/search/releases/5.9/ .

Comment: Thank you Guillaume. I don't know why but I had missed that Hibernate ORM was available with version 5.3.x :-/

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate Search versions *5.10.x* require Hibernate ORM versions *5.3.x*.

Always check for compatibility details on the Release page: http://hibernate.org/search/releases/5.10/#compatibility

I would suggest to update to **Hibernate ORM 5.3.1.Final**, which is the latest  at time of writing this.

Comment: Thank you Sanne. I don't know why but I had missed that Hibernate ORM was available with version 5.3.x :-/

Comment: @Sanne what about the hibernate-search-orm, is a good alternative? I noticed that hibernate-search is deprecated already

Comment: Sure, they are the same thing. Hibernate Search is the project name. It's organized in multiple Maven artifacts: you will need hibernate-search-orm as the main artifact. It might help to look at the source code: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search